# My friend and his three brothers are coming to lunch

Tags: riddle

> My friend is coming over for lunch, and he's bringing his siblings. He has quite a few, but he's only bringing the 3 older ones this time.
>
> I'm a little anxious. And hungry.
>
> They will arrive separately.
>
> The most punctual one is also the one that will never leave me alone.
>
> The second brother is fast behind.
>
> The third is the moody one. He's so cute I can almost eat him.
>
> My friend will come last. I like him the most because he's the most similar to me.
>
> I hope everything goes smoothly this time. I hate it when we have frictions.
>
> God, I'm starving. I might start eating before they even come.

**What's my friend's name?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your friend's name is:

> Clyde

The siblings he's bringing include:

> Blinky, the punctual one and won't leave you alone (personality Shadow)
>  Pinky, the one close behind (personality Speedy)
>  Inky, the cute one (personality Bashful, also blue and similar to the color you can eat)

About your friend:

> Clyde is most similar to you because he's yellow (personality Pokey, so he's last)

You are, of course:

> Pac-man! and that's why you're hungry!  Of course, frictions imply when the ghosts catch Pac-man....

Answer (score 2):

I believe the friend's name could be:

> Famine

My friend is coming over for lunch, and he's bringing his siblings. He has quite a few, but he's only bringing the 3 older ones this time.

> The friend and his brothers are the four horsemen of the apocalypse. They are the elder brothers as they were the first of the seven seals to be broken in the bible.

The most punctual one is also the one that will never leave me alone.
The second brother is fast behind.
The third is the moody one. He's so cute I can almost eat him.

> The one that never leaves him alone could be war, and conquest is the one that follows behind him. This would make the moody one Death.

My friend will come last. I like him the most because he's the most similar to me

> The friend is Famine, he is similar to you as you have been talking about your hunger

Comment: I like it, except that the friend has "quite a few" siblings, but the horsemen only number four.